# Problems with adding and subtracting time from/to Timers

Tags: actionscript-3

Now I am also using a timer in frame 8, which is my Gamescreen frame to try and create an energy bar, so decreasing by 1 every second, and everytime the character collides with an object then increment the value of count by 1 (which in my min is 1sec, right?), however the timer runs out prematurely, when the label is showing 3secs left after collecting 3 items the timer automatically ends, HELP ME! :)

```
var count:Number = 5; (temporary value for testing)
var theTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000, count);
theTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onTimerComplete);
theTimer.start();

function whenTimerComplete(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    theTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, whenTimerComplete); //Remove listener
    gotoAndStop("frameFive"); // Advance to score screen.
}

theTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, theCountdown);

function theCountdown(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    count--;
    timerLabel.text = count.toString()
}

//Start the timer and show in the label.
timerLabel.text=count.toString();
theTimer.start();
```

All help and a solution is VERY much appreciated.

Comment: I forgot to mention how would I go about adding 1 second onto the timer when my character collides with an object. I tried count = count + 1 but that didnt seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example countdown timer:

[image]

- [Launch Flash example](http://www.labs.jasonsturges.com/stack-overflow/examples/countdown-timer/countdown-timer.html)
- [FLA source code](http://www.labs.jasonsturges.com/stack-overflow/examples/countdown-timer/countdown-timer.fla)
- [Countdown Timer AS3 source code](http://www.labs.jasonsturges.com/stack-overflow/examples/countdown-timer/CountdownTimer.as)
- [CS6 ZIP of source code](http://www.labs.jasonsturges.com/stack-overflow/examples/countdown-timer/countdown-timer-cs6.zip)
- [CS5 ZIP of source code](http://www.labs.jasonsturges.com/stack-overflow/examples/countdown-timer/countdown-timer-cs5.zip)

Create a countdown timer class at the root of your FLA:

**CountdownTimer.as**

```
package {

import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;

public class CountdownTimer extends Timer {

    public var time:Number = 0;

    public function CountdownTimer(time:Number = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY, delay:Number = 1000) {
        super(delay, repeatCount);

        if (!isNaN(time))
            this.time = time;

        repeatCount = Math.ceil(time / delay);

        addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);
    }

    protected function timerHandler(event:TimerEvent):void {
        time -= delay;

        if (time == 0)
            dispatchEvent(new TimerEvent(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE));
    }

    public function dispose():void {
        removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);
    }

}
}
```

On the timeline of your FLA, create a timer with the total number of milliseconds to countdown:

```
var timer:CountdownTimer = new CountdownTimer(60000);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timerCompleteHandler);
timer.start();
```

In the example above, the timer will countdown for 1-minute (60-seconds).  Each second the `timerHandler` will be called.  When it reaches 0, the `timerCompleteHandler` will be called.

```
function timerHandler(event:TimerEvent):void {
    timerText.text = (timer.time / 1000).toString();
}

function timerCompleteHandler(event:TimerEvent):void {
    timerText.text = "COMPLETE";
}
```

To add time to the timer, add milliseconds to `time`.  If you want the timer to dispatch timer complete event when it reaches 0, update the `repeatCount`:

```
timer.time += 1000;
timer.repeatCount += 1;
```

Likewise to remove time from the timer, subtract milliseconds from `time`; and again, if you want the timer to dispatch timer complete event when it reaches 0, update the `repeatCount`:

```
timer.time -= 1000;
timer.repeatCount -= 1;
```

Comment: I'm not really experienced in using classes, is there a way i can do it just using eventlisteners? I appreciate the help. I am a AS3 noob :D I don't really understand classes that well therefore id find it hard to implement it

Comment: Also when I try to implement it in frame one it says packages cannot be nested